# how check all running computes list in more than one vlan

Tags: linux, shell, ping, nmap

I can get a list of running computes which do not `ICMP Echo Reply` disabled by using `nmap`, but there are some computers can not be scanned, because the computers have disabled `ICMP Echo Reply` or enabled the 'firewall' such as *nix `iptables` or `windows defender`.

We have six `vlans: 10.10.0.0/22, 10.10.4.0/22,,,10.10.20.0/22`, and my computer's ip is `10.10.17.172`, How could I get the all running computers list by command line or bash script on my computer ? Not with the `dhcp lease list` or `switch port status`.

Answer (score 0):

`nmap` can do so much more than just a ping-sweep.

Running `nmap` as root allows it to send raw network traffic. That means that devices that do not respond to ping (like default installation of Windows) will show up in the `nmap` output if you run it as root.

Note that, if you have access to the switches, and they are managed switches, getting the switch port status should give you a good list of all *wired* computers.

Likewise, your WiFi devices may report the devices that are connected.

If you have access to one of the devices (f.e. router or switch) in the VLAN, dumping the arp-table may also provide a good insight, though not necessarily a complete list.